# Solving exponential inequality, epsilion delta proof

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, epsilon-delta

I am doing a recap of what I've learned this year, I am trying to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{n}{2^n}} = 0$, using the definiton of limit (no integrals, derivatives, squeeze theorem, series etc.)
It boils down to this inequality $$\ln{n} - n\ln{2} < ln{\epsilon}$$
My initial thought was to use substitution $t = \ln{n}$, but after some time I end up with my initial inequality. Binomial Theorem did not help either. I keep going in circles, no matter what I do. Can someone give me a hint (no full solutions please, i suck at solving these kind of inequalities and want to improve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to solve that equation. You only need to find an upper bound and let this upper bound less than $\epsilon$.

For example: $x<(\frac{3}{2})^x$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$

So, you have $\frac{n}{2^n}\le \frac{(3/2)^n}{2^n}\le (\frac{3}{4})^n\le \epsilon$

Therefore, you can take $N=\lfloor{\frac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln(3/4)}}\rfloor+1$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Got so caught up in solving this inequality, that I forgot about simplests methods... Thank you. Btw, say I wanted to solve this inequality anyways, how should i go about doing it?

Comment: You are most welcome! For your original inequality (or say equation because when you solve it you need to make it "equal" first.), there is no analytical solutions. That's why we use this trick to find a new bound and to solve the new inequality with this new bound. @Kombajn

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.

$|\frac{n}{2^n}|<\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$$\quad \forall n\ge  5$

Then set $N=\max(\lfloor\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rfloor+1,5)$

Now $\forall \epsilon >0$ ,$\exists N \in\Bbb{N} $ such that $\forall n\ge N \implies $ $|\frac{n}{2^n}|<\epsilon$

Hence $(\frac{n}{2^n})$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\underline{\text{Lemma 1}}$
Let $a_n$ denote $\dfrac{2^n}{n} ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$ 
Then, the subsequence $a_4, a_5, a_6, \cdots $ 
is strictly increasing, strictly positive, and grows unbounded. 
**Proof**
$a_4 = 4.$ 
For $~\displaystyle n \geq 4,$ 
$\displaystyle a_{n+1} = a_n \times \left[\frac{2n}{n+1}\right] = a_n \times 2 \times \left[1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right] \geq a_n \times (1.6).$ 
Therefore, for all $~k \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~a_{4+k} \geq 4 \times (1.6)^k.$ 
Therefore, the subsequence $a_4, a_5, a_6, \cdots,$ is strictly positive, strictly increasing, and
grows unbounded.

---

For any $\epsilon > 0,$ Lemma 1 implies that there exists an $~N \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that for all $~n \geq N ~: n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~~\dfrac{2^n}{n} > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} \implies \dfrac{n}{2^n} < \epsilon.$

Thus, the requirement necessary to conclude that 
$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{n}{2^n} = 0$ 
has been met.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look at the row $c_n=\frac{n}{2^n}$ and in order to show that it converges to $0$, you want to show that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$ you have that $$\left|\frac{n}{2^n}-0\right|<\epsilon.$$